# Convert a FileResource to a String

Tags: java

How can I convert a `FileResource` to a `String`?

Right now I have this:

```
FileResource resource = new FileResource("data/someText.txt");
String message = "";

for(String word : resource.words()) { message = message + word; }

System.out.println(message);
```

It is creating the message, but is not adding spaces or other chars.

How can I change the `resource.words()` to something that add's all the chars?

Comment: What is `FileResource`?

Comment: You should **really** consider using a `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use resource.lines() instead of words OR .asString() - Return entire contents of this opened file as one string.

http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course2/doc/javadoc/edu/duke/FileResource.html

```
FileResource resource = new FileResource("data/someText.txt");
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

for(String line: resource.lines()) { 
  message.append(line + " ");
}

System.out.println(message);
```

Comment: An upvote for finding out (apparently) what `FileResource` the OP is talking about

Comment: That works fine! However, it is possible to add a space (" ") when the program reads a new line? Right now when a new line is readed, it not creates a space for the next word.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a space between your Loop! Its very important that you **don't** use String **concatenation**. Your speed will slow down so fast - so its important that you make your Code much more smooth by using a String Builder.

```
FileResource resource = new FileResource("data/smallHamlet.txt");
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

for(String word : resource.words())
{
    str.append(word + " "); 
}
System.out.println(message);
```

This will give you a really really hard boost in topic of performance and speed

Answer (score 1):

You can add space `" "` inside the `for` loop:

```
FileResource resource = new FileResource("data/smallHamlet.txt");
String message = "";

for(String word : resource.words())
{
    message = message + word + " "; 
}
System.out.println(message);
```

Comment: Yeah, I just did that and for now it works. However i'm not sure if this is the better solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

// Use the asString() method.

String f = "mysteryTwoKeysQuiz.txt";

FileResource fr = new FileResource(f);

String s = fr.asString();